# Syntax highlighting within a string

Tags: vim

To add a python syntax rule I will do something like this:

```
"Highlight the word self -- self.new, self
syn match pythonSelf    /\<self\>/
:hi pythonSelf          guifg=#5f9ba9
```

However, I would like to highlight any all-caps words and if they are **ONLY** in a python string. So for example, in the following image:

[image]

Line 15 should not have the `ALTER` word highlighted, but the words between lines 20-21 should be highlighted. Would it be possible to add something like:

```
syn match sqlKeyword      /[A-Z]\+/
```

But **only** if it's contained within a python string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
syn match sqlKeyword /[A-Z]\+/ containedin=pythonString contained
```

If you want to match all-caps words only, you might want to improve your pattern like this: `/\<[A-Z]\+\>/`.